# Android, JSON array into ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, json

How to parse JSON string array into Java arraylist

I have this json:

```
{
"a": [
    "A-lore ipsum 1",
    "A-lore ipsum 2",
    "A-lore ipsum 3"
],
"b": [
    "B-lore ipsum 1",       
    "B-lore ipsum 2",
    "B-lore ipsum 3"
]
}
```

this is my original code :

```
//v refers to  **a or b**
public ArrayList getJSON(String v){
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myjson);
    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    Reader reader = null;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        int n;
        while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }

        String json = writer.toString();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        list = jsonObject.getString(v); //how to create list according to category

    } catch (Exception e) {  e.printStackTrace();}

    return list;
}
```

So I would like my list to look like: 
**if v = 'a';**

```
list = {"A-lore ipsum 1","A-lore ipsum 2","A-lore ipsum 3"};
```

**if v = 'b';**

```
list = {"B-lore ipsum 1","B-lore ipsum 2","B-lore ipsum 3"};
```

Comment: What were the results when you ran this code? You can edit your question to add the results.

Comment: I edited my post, take a look now.

Comment: Having seen your update I fell my answer still meets your requirements, just change the method signature of getJSON to return SomeClass. Also jackson allows you to process the reader directly by calling mapper.readValue(reader, SomeClass.class); the caller knows which list they want, so can call getA/B on the object they are returned

Comment: It seams complicated to me, with another class. I would like to use org.json.  and some simple method that return a list of strings

Comment: I've added an answer which returns a List<String>, and uses org.json. I would strongly reccommend trying out jackson or gson however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Op has updated the question specifying that org.json is to be used, and either array or list needs to be returned.

I would strongly recommend using a more fully featured json library such as jackson - see [Android, JSON array into ArrayList<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527067/android-json-array-into-arrayliststring/28527250#28527250) for a jackson way of doing this

The below will achieve what you want with json simple, however as you can see there is some fragility which using the org.json library introduces:

```
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
final JSONArray a = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("a");
final List<String> returnArray = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    returnArray.add((String)a.get(i));
}

return returnArray;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private TextView textView;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListA = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayListB = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("myfile.json");

            int size = is.available();
            byte [] byteArray = new byte[size];

            is.read(byteArray);
            is.close();

            String json = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                JSONArray arrayA = jsonObject.getJSONArray("a");
                JSONArray arrayB = jsonObject.getJSONArray("b");


                for (int i = 0 ; i < arrayA.length(); i++) {
                    String str = (String) arrayA.get(i);
                    arrayListA.add(str);
                }

                for (int i = 0 ; i < arrayB.length(); i++) {
                    String str = (String) arrayB.get(i);
                    arrayListB.add(str);
                }

                for (String str : arrayListA) 
                        Log.d(TAG, "strA : "+str);

                for (String str : arrayListB) 
                    Log.d(TAG, "strB : "+str);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in the json you have provided above; there should be a comma between a and b:

```
{
    "a": [
        "A-lore ipsum 1",
        "A-lore ipsum 2",
        "A-lore ipsum 3"
    ],
    "b": [
        "B-lore ipsum 1",
        "B-lore ipsum 2",
        "B-lore ipsum 3"
    ]
}
```

For parsing json I'd recommend using Jackson (or Gson) rather than the org.json library; I find them nicer to interact with.

The jackson wiki is at http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome and has lots of tutorials etc

using jackson it would be:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

final SomeClass someClass = mapper.readValue(json, SomeClass.class);

List<String> a = someClass.getA();
```

where SomeClass is

```
class SomeClass {
    @JsonProperty
    private List<String> a;

    @JsonProperty
    private List<String> b;

    public SomeClass() {
    }

    public List<String> getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public List<String> getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```